# IIS and asp.net appcmd

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
Most likely causes:

    A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:

    If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
    Enable directory browsing.
        Go to the IIS Express install directory.
        Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
        Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
    Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.
```

I have the above error when I try to run my first application with VS12. Have you any idea of what is going wrong and how can I fix it ? In VS10 I guess I don't have this sort of error message

Comment: Did you try the `Things you can try` from the error message?

Comment: Yes, I did but it still didn't work

Comment: This single piece of information is useless. Are you doing ASP.NET MVC development? It seems that routing does not work, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Comment: Thanks, no I am executing a simple webpage only and my IIS is just freshly set up. I have added `<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>    
  </system.webServer>` into web.config file, and I can visit `http://localhost:63420/` which only offers a list of all files in a site I created using inetmgr. Visiting each of the files in there is still infeasible, and displaying that sort of directory browsable is also not what I am looking into, I am testing a simple masterpage :-D

Comment: Sure enough, if I set the directoryBrowse attribute option to false, I again run into the same error message. {bored!}

By the way, This error doesn't display in Webmatrix2, (it works really fine with WM2). And IO am installing VS10 to see if the same error occurs. I hope not. 80% sure it will work with vs10 because my home machine never reports this kind of error at all. I am using Windows 7 Ultimate SP1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable directory listings and/or add a default document (default.aspx, default.htm...) to the root of the site.

For more information about directory listing: [Enable directory listing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have followed and did what you suggested but i still run into the same error message